# Are Python Quart server and JS SocketIO client compatible?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, quart

On my current server, I have `large blocks of calculations` when I receive socketio events. (Server is using `Flask` + `flask-socketio`.)

I'm moving the server from **local version** serving `only one user` to **cloud version** serving `company-wise`.

I tested the tolerance of concurrency using multiple browser tabs to send requests within a short time. According to the test results, the current **default** concurrency offered by `flask-socketio` and `eventlet` doesn't seem enough.

After some investigation, I wanted to use `asyncio`, but in the end found no way to implement it together with `Flask` as well as `flask-socketio`. I found `Quart` to be a better option, which can support both `asyncio` and `websocket` at the same time.

Now the good thing is that I don't have to modify any Flask APIs, but for websocket, things are less clear:

Do I have to modify all my original socketio server-end event listeners to websocket `routes` which is used instead in Quart? Can I use python-socketio together with Quart? Can I at least keep the client-end socketio codes? -- They use event-based websocket requests, while Quart built-in websocket server seems to receive only url-based (or route-based) websocket requests.